# Drupal View Filter Invalid Option

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a view that allows the user to filter by an exposed month dropdown list.

When viewing the page in English, everything looks correct:
[image]

When viewing the page in French, the *May* option is incorrect:
[image]

Where is this list defined so that I can fix it?

Comment: Actually, it is correct https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mai

Comment: While I'm sure that is how you spell May in French, it shouldn't be translated at that point.  We use the translate interface for all translations, but for some reason what is being stored in the database is the translated version, and therefore the translation of the translation is incorrect